# How to use JOIN and SELECT AS together in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I have the two following tables.

Users Table

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | Hello | e@mail.com |
| 23 | World | p@mail.com |

Sales Table

| id | SellerId | CustomerId | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 32 | 23 | 25 |

I want to join the tables in the following way to get this result. Here I want to only get the entries where customer id is equal to 23.

| Id | SellerId | SellerName | SellerEmail | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 32 | Hello. | e@mail.com | 25. |

And also do another join this way. Here I want to only get the entries where seller id is equal to 32.

| id | CustomerId | CustomerName | CustomerEmail | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 23 | World | p@mail.com | 25. |

My code for both the tables is

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)

class Sales(Base):
    __tablename__="sales"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    seller_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    amount = Column(Integer, index=True)
```

I was able to achieve this using raw SQL with the following

```
SELECT (sales.id), name as SellerName, email as SellerEmail, Amount
FROM sales
LEFT JOIN user ON sales.SellerId = user.id
WHERE CustomerId = 23
```

Please help with doing the same using SqlAlchemy Session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = (    
    session.query(
        Sales.id,
        Users.name.label('SellerName'),
        Users.email.label('SellerEmail'),
        Sales.amount
    )
    .select_from(Sales)
    .outerjoin(Users, Users.id == Sales.seller_id)
    .filter(Sales.customer_id == 23)
)
```